# VMWare vm jumps to different times when it is idle for a while and causes Kerberos authentication to fail

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, kerberos

I have an issue and trying to get to the root cause of it.

Setup:

- I have a cluster of virtual machines, one of them being a Kerberos KDC and another one being a Java-based webserver that authenticates to other services via Kerberos.

Symptoms:

- The webserver, if it is idle for a while fails randomly (sometimes it goes for two weeks without issue), and the logs show that the Kerberos ticket renewal did not work because the clock skew is too great. The time shown in the logs is jumping to any random time between 1970 and 2050, which is strange.

Temporary fix:

- I set up a Jenkins job that pings this server every 15 minutes. Ever since then, the problem never occurred again.

I have done some internet search and found different issues with VMWare and time, but nothing that fits this profile. I tried to remove the setting to get the time from host but use an external NTP server. All of it did not help.

I am just wondering if someone in this community has encountered something similar, and would know a setting in VMWare that could prevent the symptoms from happening. I am certainly unhappy about the temporary fix and would like to rid of it as soon as I can. Everything seems to point to something that VMWare does if a machine is idle, but I can't point my finger to it...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Additional Remark: I have the same set of servers set up in a different environment too, where VMWare is not running, and there I never encountered this problem. This is why I tied that problem to VMWare